# Access to inner HTML of icefaces Rich Text Editor

Tags: java, icefaces

My question related to Icefaces and its Rich Text Editor.
Is it posible to have an access to html source of the Rich Text Editor text using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().getText();` . editor1 will be the id of the inputRichText